# Use alias in layout templates ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to use a variable in template. 
I have a class call services;
need who this atributes, after iterable, as variable type alias.

In django we use, Example: `{% firstof "0" as cont %}`. I use the first element as cont.

In ruby on rails templates, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you please add more details by giving examples and formatting code correctly

Comment: In my data collections i need to rank the elements by your %, (odd or pair). In django the possible soluction are call some as. example {%firstof "0" as cont%}.

Comment: Please edit your question directly. You should be able to add a code block which makes it easier to understand to these who want to answer. Also try to find a tag that would clearly show you are talking about RoR templates. Anyway, good luck with your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find Ruby String Interpolation.

```
age  = 33
name = "Jesus"

"Hello, my name is #{name} & I'm #{age} years old."
```

> "Hello, my name is Jesus & I'm 33 years old."

for more detail visit here [string interpolation](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/07/ruby-string-concatenation/)

Comment: I whant manipulate blocks with a variable in templates ruby on rails.

Comment: you mean html.erb file?

Comment: <%= "Hello, my name is #{name} & I'm #{age} years old." %> don'e miss **=** equal sign otherwise you can't see it in templates.

Comment: yaeah, to manipualte html.erb. Im trying: in controller i create the variable aux, in my html.erb file i use this <%if aux == 0%>, but i need who this aux varing with services values, to change the value to show in index.html.erb

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting you exactly. if you trying to find the controller variable in a template,  you have to create instance variable. for that in controller you have to declare  @aux = 'what you want' and then you can print it in view file <%= aux %> like this

Answer (score 0):

Also, i do this with a variable in controller.

The @aux solve this quest

in controller:
@aux = 0

in my html.erb

do this...

do this...